# C++ decode void pointer nicely for Matlab mex

Tags: c++, matlab, void-pointers, mex

I'm trying to write a C++ mex function for Matlab that can handle multiple datatypes.  Matlab gives me an `mxArray*`, from which I can retrieve a `void*` for the data, and an `mxClassID` telling me the datatype.  So I can do something like:

```
void *data = mxGetData(mxarray);
switch (mxGetClassID(mxarray)) {
  case mxDOUBLE_CLASS:
    my_function(static_cast<double *>(data));
  ...
```

`my_function` is templated, so this handles different datatypes nicely. But it's still very annoying to need to have this switch for every possible `my_function1`, `my_function2`, etc.

So far, the solution I've come up with is to use a functional approach and have a method that accepts a functor:

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename FunctorType>
ReturnType mxarr_apply(const mxArray *inarr, FunctorType functor) {
  void *data = mxGetData(inarr);
  switch (mxGetClassID(inarr)) {
    case mxDOUBLE_CLASS:
      return (ReturnType) functor(static_cast<double *>(data));
    ...
```

This way I can put my logic in the functor (with `operator()` templated) and not have to recreate the switch over and over.

But I wonder if there is some other way? In Java I think I could just have a function that translates the `mxClassID` directly into a `class` reference that could then be used to instantiate a type flexibly at runtime, but this doesn't seem to be an option in C++.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct. There's no way in C++ to get a class reference at runtime. You have to write the switch, at least once.

Comment: Thanks much.  And for writing the switch only once, the functor approach is the way to go?  Or are there other options?  This setup becomes especially painful when dealing with output.  I find I am limited to side-effect based output for many situations.

Answer (score 0):

If you face the need to write multiple switches you might want to either hide it's logic into a factory, that would return the right functor given the type

```
void *data = mxGetData(mxarray);
functor func = FunctorFactory::Get(mxGetClassID(mxarray));
func (reinterpret_cast<double*>(data));
```

or simply create a map (preferrably unordered or a hash) of types to functors.

```
void *data = mxGetData(mxarray);
functor func = functorMap[mxGetClassID(mxarray)]; // need to check for key availability
func (reinterpret_cast<double*>(data));
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting suggestions.  For the functor factory pattern, the return types of the functor would be fixed, right?  I make my functors with templated `operator()`, so that generally handles getting the right one by type.

Comment: I think static_cast is okay for this situation; I changed my examples from C-style to static_cast.